# How to reuse sqlalchemy declarative models in different database schema

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I am working on implementing sets of sqlalchemy declarative models for multiple database schemas. These database schemas are highly similar in table design. I would like to be able to reuse as much of the common model code (column definitions, relations etc.) as possible across the sets of models for each schema.
(Please note, the schemas in question are 99% identical.)

As a small example:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Integer, String

Base = declarative_base()

class Person(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'person'
    name = Column(String, primary_key=True)
    age = Column(Integer)
```

If I now want to introduce a new attribute Person column 'height' that only exists in one schema and not the other, how can I go about defining it whilst reusing the existing Person column definitions?

So far, I have tried using declarative mixins to define the common functionality and then mix these into classes that inherit from different schema-specific bases. However, this is unsatisfactory because even the majority of identical models have to be declared as mixins, and a  declarative class declared once for schema (inheriting from the appropriate base and the mixin). Given that the schemas are similar this seems like a lot of boilerplate code.

Is there a better way to do it?